# How to split a string in Java using .indexOf()

Tags: java, string, substring, indexof, lastindexof

I am a trying to create a program that takes input from the user (assuming 3 words) and outputs  the first word capitalised, the second in lower case and the third word only the first two characters. I don't understand why the third one is printed whole plus the first two characters and not just the first 2 characters. Thanks so much! So far I have this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Words {

    public static void main (String[] args){

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        String line = keyboard.nextLine();

        String word1 = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(" ")).toUpperCase();
        String word2 = line.substring(line.indexOf(" ") +1).toLowerCase();
        String word3 = line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(" ")+1).substring(0, 
        ,2);

        System.out.println(word1 + " " + word2 + " " + word3);
    }

}
```

**Output:**

> JAVA is fun fu

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I'm trying to find out how to split a string into words with the means of method indexOf not accessing characters with this method. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You say

`String word2 = line.substring(line.indexOf(" ") +1).toLowerCase();`

which makes `word2` assume the value of `is fun`. Also, for word 3, you say `.substring(0,2)` (as substring's 2nd number is non-inclusive) which brings in the `fu`, creating the output `JAVA is fun fu`.

An alternative implementation could be to just Split the string by space and assign it to the three variables easily.

Comment: Like so:

    String s[] = line.split(" ");
    String word1 = s[0].toUpperCase;
    String word2 = s[1].toLowerCase;
    String word3 = s[2];

    // Check if word3 contains at least 2 characters:
    word3 = word3.substring(0, Math.min(2, word3.length()));
    
    System.out.println(word1 + " " + word2 + " " + word3);

Comment: @HeikoJakubzik You should not feed code: at least that is what I feel. You should give enough subtle hints to the questioner so that he can think through his code, realize his mistakes, correct them and learn :)

Comment: I don't want to resort to a solution where I use an array but I am trying to use of indexOf method to set the boundaries for each token.

Comment: @DianaConstantina yes, and parts of your code can be improved to make it happen (Based upon my answer). You need to define the ending index of the second word. Substring without the ending index assumes the entire string that follows. Something like `line.substring(line.indexOf(" ") +1, line.lastIndexOf(" ")).toLowerCase();` should work.

Comment: Thanks so much Parijat Purohit! It does work indeed!

Comment: @DianaConstantina glad I could help. :)